# Emailing a Django PDF file without saving in a FileField

Tags: django, weasyprint

I have been struggling to email a pdf file am generating(using weasy print),I would like to be able to email directly without saving the file in my model object(If I could just save it in a temporary location and email it).But keep Getting this error.
**'file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str**

```
pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html,
                base_url=settings.MEDIA_ROOT).write_pdf()

certificate = SimpleUploadedFile(
    'Certificate-' + '.pdf', pdf_file, content_type='application/pdf')

attachment = certifcate.read()

msg.attach_file(attachment, 'application/pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to generate pdf file on the fly,save it to a temporary location   and email it.I stopped using `SimpleUploadedFile` and used the `NamedTemporaryFile` function from `tempfile` python module.it allows you to return a file-like object that can be used as a temporary storage area, which you can write something to it, read it from it. here is the [link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html) to docs and some reference to a [blog](http://echorand.me/tempfilenamedtemporaryfile-in-python.html) on tempfile

```
     pdf_file = HTML(string=rendered_html,
                 base_url=settings.MEDIA_ROOT).write_pdf()

     temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
     temp.write(pdf_file)
     temp.seek(0)

     msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
        subject, message, sender, receivers)
     msg.attach_file(temp.name, 'application/pdf')
     msg.send()
```